# send email via email client,

Tags: javascript, email, outlook

In my project on click of a button I need to open outlook with send to, sent from and email body are filled.
here is my code

```
var a = $("#emailLink");
        var emlBody =
            encodeURIComponent(result.data.EmailBody);

        var url = 'mailto:' + result.data.ClientEmail + '?subject=' + result.data.Subject + '&body=' + emlBody;
        $(a).attr("href", url);
        a[0].click();
```

body length goes beyond 2000 length, so i get this message

> Launched external handler for 'client@mail.com?subject=a%20subject&body=a%20long%20message'.

how do i fix this, also how can i add text formatting to work in outlook

Answer (score 0):

The [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol doesn't support any formatting for the message body. This is a plain text property.